# Database Merge onto single Server

Tags: database, merge

Question is I have a backup Server with 2 years of data on it using MS SQL, I also have a production server database, I want to merge the two onto a single server but having conflicts because most of tables are the same.I having been doing research into data integration as well as SQL server Business Intelligence, but really can't get a grasp of it. Also I'm trying to weight out the pros and cons.

I know by having this much data on one database will take a long time to run reports.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for a data migration:

1. Decide if you really want to do this, for reasons of scale, difficulty, cost/benefit, politics, whatever.
2. Figure out what the new design of the system will be.
3. Design system to import old data from arbitrary sources into new server
4. Design and make sure everything using old systems can use new system
5. Make very very sure you're all set.
6. Actually implement what was designed in stages 3 and 4, completing the migration.

You say "tables have the same name".  That either means you need to have step 3 merge the data from both sources, or it means that you need to make the future tables have different names in step 2 (which will matter a lot for step 4).